# Calling an api from Chef (curl works)

Tags: chef-infra

I have been trying to call an api from within Chef and then parse the result, at the moment however I can't even call the api

This works

```
curl -X PUT -H "X-API-KEY:The Key secret"  -d "va1=a@var2-b" https://example.com/v1/endpointl1/endpointl2
```

I have tried various things, my best attempt so far is

```
Chef::HTTP.new('https://example.com').put('/v1/endpointl1/endpointl2', 'va1=a@var2-b',"X-API-KEY:The Key secret")
```

But I get ERROR: can't convert String into Hash

Which I presume is because of the headers (X-API-KEY bit) not being in the right format

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how I can call an api correctly

Thanks

Grant

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it via an `execute` where `command` uses `curl ...`

My own code example:

```
execute "curl-to-api" do
  command "curl -m 5 -i -X POST -d ... etc ... #{chat_url}"
  ignore_failure true
end
```

Comment: Why ignore_failure ?

Comment: Since if the curl command failed, I didnt want the recipe to stop.

Comment: So in a case of a cluster lock call, you'll happily continue and maybe break the service. Without insight on what is the goal of the call,  promoting ignore_failure is a bad idea IMO.

Comment: What is a cluster lock call? In this case, wouldnt it be reasonable to ignore the failure of the execute block (posting the chat message.... maybe if chat is down... dont want to stop the other deployments). I guess I need to study up on error handling / exceptions in ruby / chef.

Comment: If you post to an app server to say you're going offline and set a lock so the chef run on the other server won't stop the service until this one is back, ignoring the failure to set up the lock has a good chance to drive a service interruption. Chef itself has no mechanism for this, so we usually use zookeeper or any other api system to set/get a lock status

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, it helped me focus.  I was slightly confused by this one as I tweaked it a bit and got a 406 message, it turns out that I even got that with curl but it also gave me a server message (json) with detail

This is what I did in the end

```
response=Chef::HTTP.new('https://api.pagely.com').put('/v1/domains/single', 'var1=abc&var2=def', ({'X-API-KEY' => 'mysecret'}))
print response
json = JSON.parse response
pgsiteid = json['id']
print pgsiteid
```

Looks like it works.  It would have been nice if Chef\Ruby didn't moan at the 406 error, but I guess that is more an issue with the api

The last bit is me getting a value from the response

Thanks

Grant

Comment: What about describing your real problem than a XY problem ? you problem is getting a value from this API, not making the request at all.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rewrite this, check out https://coderanger.net/chef-tips/#4. I know SO doesn't like just linking docs but if someone else wants to transcribe, go for it. Basically you want to use `Chef::HTTP`. It has some accessors for simple requests, and returns `Net::HTTP` response objects. The only change from you have there should be to put the header data as a hash instead of a string I think.